# Dates displaying as text in excel pivot when retrieving from sql server 2008

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008

Inserting a table into SQL server 2008 R2 and retrieving that data in an Excel 2010 workbook, via  Data>From Other Sources>From SQL Server. Dates are retrieved as text. For the table, tried Convert, Cast, Datediff keywords to create a "date" field. In the Excel workbook tried to format columns as Date before refresh and Excel still retrieves those fields as text. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the date columns in the SQL database to the DATETIME data type. Excel reads DATETIMEs as date fields by default. DATEs come through as text.